# move_group Spend a lot of memory

Tags: ros, memory, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I run the pi_robot example than I get in 《ros by example 2》,the move_group almost have spent no memory.
but for my robot It have spent 1.5G memory.

there are same problem ,when I use moveit assistant load my urdf It spend 2G memory.but for pi_robot ,It almost spent no memory.

thank for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247014/move_group-spend-a-lot-of-memory/) by [clark_txh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28091/clark_txh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just taking a guess, but it's likely that this is related to your other question: [It is likely there are too many vertices in collision geometry](http://answers.ros.org/question/247228).

Can you try and see whether reducing the quality of your meshes influences this?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clark_txh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28091/clark_txh/) on 2016-11-21**:
I have used Meshmixer to reduce the meshes.
but I can use the moveit assistant to load my urdf now.

and,I can use rviz display the urdf.It look like OK.

what's error in here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-21**:
I'm not sure I follow: what is the error in where?